# Sonar Lite Mode Aux Classpath & Ivy Dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, maven, ivy, sonarqube

Our project currently uses Ivy for its dependency management. We would really like to integrate our Hudson build server with Sonar. So far this has been a relatively simple and straightforward task. Of course we have set Sonar up to run in Sonar Lite mode (as we are not a Maven project).

Unfortunately, when our Sonar bytecode scan kicks in we get a lot of the following:

> [WARN]  Class 'XXX' is not accessible
>   through the ClassLoader. [WARN]  Class
>   'XXX' is not accessible through the
>   ClassLoader. ... [WARN]  Class 'XXX'
>   is not accessible through the
>   ClassLoader.

I understand that this is because our dependencies are not defined in our Sonar Lite dummy POM file and hence the libraries are not being picked to be traversed during the analysis.

The [Sonar installation documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Java+Projects) mentions that the dependencies must be added to the aux classpath via the Maven pom file for this to be rectified. However, there does not seem to be any way to painlessly sync these dependencies with our ivy dependencies (of which there are hundreds). We obviously are looking for a way to define our dependencies without the need to replicate each one in our dummy pom file.

[Several issues](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?reset=true&jqlQuery=project+%3D+SONAR+AND+%28summary+%7E+%22Lite+Dependencies%22+OR+description+%7E+%22Lite+Dependencies%22+OR+comment+%7E+%22Lite+Dependencies%22%29) raised on the Sonar codehaus site (such as [this one](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-1720)) seem to dance around the same feature that I'm looking for but none seem to offer a reasonable solution (unless I'm missing something).

Has anyone dealt with this situation before and has a reasonably good solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sonar lite mechanism now appears to be deprecated with Sonar 2.6.

Two new ways to integrate Sonar with a non Maven build:

- [ANT task](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+ANT)
- [Java runner](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+a+simple+Java+Runner)

The ANT task is tailor made for combination with ivy's control of the build and runtime classpaths (Using configurations):

```
<!--
  Uses ivy to download dependencies
  -->

  <target name="dependencies" description="Resolve project dependencies and set classpaths">
    <ivy:resolve/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="compile.path"  conf="compile"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="runtime.path"  conf="runtime"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="test.path"     conf="test"/>
    <ivy:cachepath pathid="anttasks.path" conf="anttasks"/>
  </target>

  <!--
  Perform source code analysis
  -->

  <target name="sonar-init" description="Declare sonar ant task">
    <taskdef uri="antlib:org.sonar.ant" 
             resource="org/sonar/ant/antlib.xml" 
             classpathref="anttasks.path"/>
  </target>

  <target name="sonar" depends="test,sonar-init" description="Run the Sonar code analysis tool">
    <ivy:info/>

    <sonar:sonar workDir="${sonar.workDir}" key="${ivy.organisation}:${ivy.module}" version="${ivy.revision}">
      <!-- Project layout -->
      <sources>
        <path location="${build.srcDir}"/>
      </sources>
      <tests>
        <path location="${build.testDir}"/>
      </tests>
      <binaries>
        <path location="${build.outputDir}"/>
        <path location="${build.testOutputDir}"/>
      </binaries>
      <libraries>
        <path refid="test.path"/>
      </libraries>
      <!-- Additional Sonar configuration -->
      <property key="sonar.java.source" value="1.5"/>
      <property key="sonar.java.target" value="1.5"/>
    </sonar:sonar>
  </target>
```

Additionally note how the ivy **info** task can be used to set the Sonar key and version.

Comment: Thanks for this piece of information Mark. I feel that I should rightfully mark this answer as correct (sorry Chris but the better answer came along).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried an XSL transformation of the ivy.xml into your dummy pom.xml?

Comment: Chris, no I didn't consider using an XSLT but I like the idea. I will look into it.

Comment: A bit of a Google search reveals the makepom ant task (http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/2.2.0/use/makepom.html). This might be a nice way of integrating what I seek into our existing build scripts.

I'll look into it further...

Comment: Chris. After discovering that Sonar takes 24+ hours to run a full analysis of our project, we have decided not to integrate it. Hence, I have not devoted any time to verifying your proposed solution. That being said, I see no reason why it would not work as it seems quite sound. So, I will accept this answer (as there is nothing better offered).

Thanks Chris.